# Lotus Notes Formula Language

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

I have a field which contains 10 digits (i.e 10 numerals) and I want to replace that field value with only the last 4 digits of that field.

Comment: Also you need to tell us whether the field type is Text but just happens to be filled with digits, or the field type is actually Number.

Comment: Maybe the keywords '@Right, '@Text, '@toNumber may help you...

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a simpler way to do this, but I'm presuming that you want to have your output as Text, and that you don't know if your input is text or number.

Also, assuming that your input is in a field called *inputText*, of unknown type, and that the number of digits you want to return is in a field called *digits*, you could use this code:

```
tmp := @Right(@Text(@TextToNumber(@Text(InputText))/@Power(10; @TextToNumber(@Text(digits)))); ".");
tmp := @If(@Right(@Text(@TextToNumber(InputText)); 1) = "0"; tmp + "0"; tmp);
@If(@IsError(tmp); "Error"; tmp)
```

Alternatively, as umeli suggested, you could look up @Text, @Right and @TextToNumber in Designer Help, and come up with something simpler.